# How to perform int operations in pandas dataframe with NaN elements

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, nan

I have a dataframe that looks something like:

```
    Brand    Price
0   toronto  16-Aug-16
1   quebec   18-May-17
2   brampton 18-May-17
3   toronto  31-Dec-97
```

My code at the moment is as follows:

```
df["YEAR_TORONTO"] = np.nan
df["YEAR_TORONTO"] = np.where(df["Brand"] == "toronto", df["Price"], np.nan)
df["YEAR_TORONTO"] = df["YEAR_TORONTO"].str[-2:]
df["YEAR_TORONTO"] = np.where(isinstance(df["YEAR_TORONTO"], str) and df["YEAR_TORONTO"].astype(int) >= 20, "19" + df["YEAR_TORONTO"], "20" + df["YEAR_TORONTO"])
df["YEAR_TORONTO"] = df["YEAR_TORONTO"].fillna(0).astype(int).astype(object).where(df["YEAR_TORONTO"].notnull())
```

This gives me a result that looks like:

```
    Brand    Price       YEAR_TORONTO
0   toronto  16-Aug-16   2016
1   quebec   18-May-17   NaN
2   brampton 18-May-17   NaN
3   toronto  31-Dec-97   2097
```

I'm aware that the `2097` instead of the `1997` is due to the `and` condition in my logic, but I'm not sure how to fix this due to the NaN values interfering and giving errors. Any help correcting this code would be greatly beneficial, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you could use `to_datetime` and use the accessor `dt.year` to extract the year. Then use `where` to replace the rows that are not toronto with `pd.NA` to keep the year as integer

```
df["YEAR_TORONTO"] = (pd.to_datetime(df['Price']).dt.year
                        .where(df['Brand'].eq('toronto'), pd.NA))
print(df)
      Brand      Price YEAR_TORONTO
0   toronto  16-Aug-16         2016
1    quebec  18-May-17         <NA>
2  brampton  18-May-17         <NA>
3   toronto  31-Dec-97         1997
```